# Is it possible to use a JSON Object as a Variable in Activiti and use specific Nodes as Variable

Tags: expression, activiti, juel

I want to use a JSON Object in the activity variable

so i have a declared JSON Object:

```
[
  "test.jpeg",
  "test.xml",
  "test_de2.mp4",
  "test_season.jpeg",
  "test_series.jpeg",
  "test_v05.mp4"
 ]
```

I put this as a process variable :

```
processVariables.put("result",jsonObject)
```

is it possible to acess a single element via the expression language?

like

```
${result[0]}
```

or something like this?

I tried a bit around but it did not work. I can't even find a good documentation for the expression language used in activity.

Comment: no. you will have to use `Javascript` first to parse it into your `JSON`, by default the engine will take it as a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the engine will assume it to be a `String` as there are currently no datatype for `JSON` in process variables. However, you can use JavaScript to parse your string to JSON.

Comment: Kindly elaborate on how to use JavaScript.  I am editing the BPMN XML using Eclipse IDE and the only options I see for language under expression language are Java and XPath.

Comment: You can parse using java as well.